# Render remote view in local layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, microservices

My organization is considering re-implementing an existing Rails monolith as a collection of Rails services. For the content layer, our thought was that our API gateway would contain the layout information for the whole app, and would request individual views via HTTP. Individual services would then render their templates and send them back via HTTP as rendered HTML.

My question is this: is there a mechanism in Rails to request remote content via HTTP, to render the received HTML into an ERB/HAML layout template, and then to serve the fully rendered HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like requesting that information in a controller and then outputting it as a string in an ERB template?

Is there some other requirement that I'm missing?

**Controller**

```
def index
  @content = body_of_request_to_service
end
```

**View**

```
...
<%= @content %>
...
```

But, I wouldn't recommend this style of microservices using Ruby *(unless you have a dev-team that understands how to handle async Ruby IO)*. A good rule of thumb is to only have one blocking service request per client request.

Answer (score 0):

When you render a template in Rails, nothing restricts you in terms of where the markup comes from. Regularly it would come from a locally found `*.html.erb` template.

When a pre-rendered html piece comes from an external source you can do this:

```
render html: my_html_string.html_safe
```

If you want a layout, then:

```
render html: my_html_string.html_safe, layout: 'my_layout'
```

The `my_html_string` could be served by the external source either with html format renderer or as a string to be later serialized to e.g., json.

```
@my_html_string = render_to_string(
  template: 'templates/my_template.html.erb',
  layout: false
)
```